# how to send request get api to spring server use react redux have token

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, redux

i use server is spring boot have spring security and client is react use fetch send request get data have token not success

error here:
[image: error here]

request:
[image]

response:

[image]

postman success:
[image]

code get data in client

```
let header = new Headers({
        'X-Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    });
    console.log(header)
    return fetch(`http://localhost:8080/account/current`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: header
    })
        .then(checkHttpStatus)
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(receiveProtectedData(response.data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                dispatch(loginUserFailure(error));
                dispatch(push('/login'));
            }
        })
```

code server :

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(Constants.LOGIN_PATH, Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN_PATH).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**",
                    "/validatorUrl").permitAll()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(buildLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the token instead of using template literal and check to see if it works?

Comment: hi.
i had use token from server send and try hardcoding problem same it not have change

Comment: In your postman request you use 'Authorization' instead of 'X-Authorization', can you try using 'Authorization' instead?

Comment: yes i had instead it but not have change.